# Cumulative distribution function applied to random variable with a constant

Tags: probability, statistics, cumulative-distribution-functions, quantile-function

For a random variable $X$ with cumulative distribution function $F$ one can show that $F(X)$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ by means of the quantile function. (see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77845/inverse-function-for-a-non-decreasing-cdf for a quite nice explanation).

Now, what about $F(X+x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$? What is its distribution? Any ideas?

Edit 1: Following the first comment, we obtain that $F(X+x)$ has cdf (denoted $\tilde F$) 
\begin{align}
\tilde F (y) = P( F(X+x) \leq y) = P(X \leq F^{-1}(y) -x) = F(F^{-1}(y)-x ).
\end{align}
I don't see what distribution this is... But could we at least say something about the expectation of $F(X+x)$ then?

Comment: $F(X+x)\leq y$ iff $X\leq F^{-1}(y)-x$...

Comment: Note also, that it is not true that $F(X)$ is uniform **for any** random variable X with arbitrary cdf $F$.

Comment: @NCh: Why not? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @joriki ... Suppose $X = 0,1$, each with probability $1/2$.  Compute $F$ and $F(X)$.

Comment: Or simply realise that $F(X)$ still attains at most two different values (almost surely).